# catkin_make causes hard shutdown

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have encountered a very strange problem and can't seem to find any other instance of the problem. I have a catkin workspace that I tried to perform catkin_make on. For some reason, when I execute catkin_make, it runs for a while and then my computer blacks out completely. I believe that is a hard shutdown of the computer.

So, I have no idea why executing catkin_make should cause a hard shutdown and was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to why that would be happening. I don't believe my CPU is overheating and I have done a SMART self-test and it comes back ok.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214444/catkin_make-causes-hard-shutdown/) by [jpws](https://answers.ros.org/users/23324/jpws/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out the solution was what gvdhoorn recommended; Running

> catkin_make -j1

seems to fix the problem. Still don't really know the root cause but it does suggest that overheating might have been occurring. Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it!

---

Originally posted by [jpws](https://answers.ros.org/users/23324/jpws/) with karma: 1 on 2015-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-26**:
That is not really a *solution*, but more of a work-around. Does your computer ever show these symptoms if you run other CPU/GPU intensive applications? Do you have a swap partition setup? CPU temp is easily monitored: [SensorInstallHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please add some more info: version of ROS, how you installed it, your OS, and most importantly: the layout of your workspace (nr of pkgs, are you overlaying, etc). Also: quick test: do you observe the same when running `catkin_make -j1`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you see an error like "c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)" when you catkin_make? This is usually due to insufficient memory while compiling a number of packages at a time. I suggest you to try and build one package at a time with  `catkin_make --pkg package_name` .

---

Originally posted by [mpai227](https://answers.ros.org/users/23104/mpai227/) with karma: 21 on 2015-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1